# Repeating a mesh instead of stretching it

Tags: unity

I would like to put acoustic foam into a case object:

[image]

To do that, I have created a foam object:

[image]

Now I'm having a really hard time to cover the case in Unity with this object:

[image]

I have to adjust multiple foam objects absolutely exactely besides each other. This is really time taking.

I was thinking that it would be great that if I could use scaling, and instead of scretching, Unity would repeat the object.

Is that perhaps somehow possible?

Thank you very much!

Comment: This looks like a good candidate for parallax occlusion mapping, rather than using geometry at all.

Comment: Or if the view of the box is fixed, then you could also pre-render it. Doing this using actual models is very wasteful and could introduce performance problems.

Comment: Why not just use normal maps?

Comment: I would really recommend you to create this surface not with a detailed mesh but with a simple plane with a tiling texture. You can use a normal map and optionally a height map to imitate the 3d structure of the surface. That would be far easier and far more performance-friendly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't think rendering performance might be an issue, you could consider placing the foam object with a Script. This way it would be 100% precise. If you prefer seeing and working with the result in Edit mode, an Editor Script might be the better choice.

Here is an example for Instantiating a prefab mesh as children of the GameObject the script is attached to:

```
public class ReplicateMesh : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int rows;
    public int columns;
    public GameObject meshPrefab;

    public void Start()
    {
        if (meshPrefab == null)
            return;

        for (int rowIndex=0; rowIndex < rows; rowIndex++)
            for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < columns; colIndex++)
                Instantiate(meshPrefab, new Vector3(rowIndex - rows/2f, 0, colIndex - columns/2f), Quaternion.identity, this.transform);
    }
}
```

*Note:* This example assumes the prefab mesh has unity scale. If your use-case requires different scaling, a position offset needs to be considered when computing the position of the prefab instances.

---

If you prefer instantiating the prefab mesh in edit mode you can change the code to be triggered from an Editor GUI. For exmaple, check out the tutorial about how to add a Button to a CustomInspector: https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/interface-essentials/adding-buttons-custom-inspector

This way, you could generate the majority of the instances via code and add/remove/adjust some manually.